# How do I remove all before a specific text on each line in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, text, replace, notepad++

I have a file containing a thousand lines like this:

> N'AN2ID', N'Best. Fluorid premium (EL) AN2ID', 1, N'AN2ID', N'', 0, 0,
>   0, N'Anorganik Messlabor 1 (EG 36) - IC', NULL, N'IRCode', 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'987b57da-dc85-4e5c-a36a-e40829ccc0e0',
>   N'IonenC', 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
>
> N'WE811M018', N'Abf. EOX', 1, N'', N'', 0, 0, 0,
>   N'Feststoff-Probenvorbereitung', NULL, N'IRCode', 0, 1, 0, 0, NULL,
>   N'e71f44e4-dff2-4d3a-8a64-655eeb16e1ff', NULL, NULL,
>   N'987b57da-dc85-4e5c-a36a-e40829ccc0e0', N'FS-PV', 0, 0, 0, NULL,
>   NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
>
> N'EW-EOX-FS', N'Extraktion EOX FS (ohne Vortest)', 1, N'', N'', 0, 0,
>   0, N'Probenaufarbeitung Lipophile Stoffe', NULL, N'IRCode', 0, 0, 0,
>   0, NULL, N'2f49c200-a06e-472d-94ca-e5a37eaceee7', NULL, NULL,
>   N'987b57da-dc85-4e5c-a36a-e40829ccc0e0', N'LiposEOX', 0, 0, 0, NULL,
>   NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

On each line, I would like to remove all the text before this: "0, 0, 0, N'XXX'"

For example on the first row, all the text before `N'', 0, 0, 0, N'Anorganik Messlabor 1 (EG 36) - IC'` is `N'AN2ID', N'Best. Fluorid premium (EL) AN2ID', 1, N'AN2ID', N'',`

Is there a way to do it with a regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*?(?= 0, 0, 0, N')`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               : stat of line
.*?             : 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
(?=             : start lookahead
   0, 0, 0, N'  : literally
)               : end lookahead
```

- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *Check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*

**Result for given example:**

```
 0, 0, 0, N'Anorganik Messlabor 1 (EG 36) - IC', NULL, N'IRCode', 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, N'987b57da-dc85-4e5c-a36a-e40829ccc0e0', N'IonenC', 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

 0, 0, 0, N'Feststoff-Probenvorbereitung', NULL, N'IRCode', 0, 1, 0, 0, NULL, N'e71f44e4-dff2-4d3a-8a64-655eeb16e1ff', NULL, NULL, N'987b57da-dc85-4e5c-a36a-e40829ccc0e0', N'FS-PV', 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

 0, 0, 0, N'Probenaufarbeitung Lipophile Stoffe', NULL, N'IRCode', 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, N'2f49c200-a06e-472d-94ca-e5a37eaceee7', NULL, NULL, N'987b57da-dc85-4e5c-a36a-e40829ccc0e0', N'LiposEOX', 0, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

**Find:** `^.*?(0, 0, 0, N'.*)`
**Replace:** `$1`

Clear the box: `.` matches newline.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with this

Find `(?m-s)^.+?(?=0,\s*0,\s*0,\s*N'[^'\r\n]*')`
Replace with nothing.

https://regex101.com/r/rSEKAn/2